# How do I display an editor for a list of child models to link to the parent model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following model relationship set up via EF:

```
public class Purpose
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Purpose> Purposes { get; set; }
}
```

My purposes are pre-defined in the database, and one `Item` can have many `Purposes` (think of them almost like "tags"). A user cannot add a new `Purpose` on the `Item` editor, they can only choose from pre-existing ones.

I am new to MVC and am trying to create CRUD operations for my `Item` class. I scaffolded my EF models so I have the basics (e.g. it allows me to edit the `Name` property because that is a simple property), but it didn't scaffold the more complex relationships.

What I'm looking for is, on the Edit view, a list of checkboxes which lists each `Purpose` in the database, and when one or more are checked, it adds them to the `List<Purpose>` relationship on the `Item` class. This is what I have in my `Item.cshtml` view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Purposes)
```

I have created a Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Purpose.cshtml editor template, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put in it or how this will ultimately link up to my main `Item` view.

Comment: Just strongly type `Purpose.cshtml` as `Puspose` and then add the form (or let VS generate it via scaffolding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View models are your friend. Include a boolean property to indicate the selected `Purpose` objects

```
public class PurposeVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class ItemVM
{
  public int Id { get; set; } // only required for an edit view model
  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<PurposeVM> Purposes { get; set; }
```

}

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ItemVM model = new ItemVM();
  // map all purposes from database, for example
  model.Purposes = db.Purposes.Select(p => new PurposeVM()
  {
    Id = p.Id,
    Name = p.Name
  });
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ItemVM model)
{
}
```

View

```
@model ItemVM
@using(Html.BeinForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
  for(int i = 0; i < Model.Purposes.Count;i++)
  {
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Purposes[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Purposes[i].IsSelected, Model.Purposes[i].Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Purposes[i].Id) // plus hidden input for name if you want to post that as well
  }
  <input type="submit" />
}
```